# Vuetify File upload

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, vuetify.js

I have a form where I use the Vuetify `v-file-input` component:

```
  <v-file-input chips multiple label="File(s)" v-model="file.files"></v-file-input>
```

My data object looks like this:

```
 data: () => ({
    file: {
      files: null,
      directory: 0,
    }
 })
```

When I `console.log` the form data the `files` object returns an empty object. How can I get the file data to pass it to my Laravel back-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a the `change` event and a `FileReader` ...

```
   <v-file-input chips multiple @change="addFiles()" 
          label="File(s)" v-model="file.files"></v-file-input>

   methods: {
        addFiles(){
            this.files.forEach((file, f) => {

                this.readers[f] = new FileReader();
                this.readers[f].onloadend = (e) => {

                    let fileData = this.readers[f].result
                    let imgRef = this.$refs.file[f]
                    imgRef.src = fileData
                    console.log(fileData)

                    // send to server here...
                }

                this.readers[f].readAsDataURL(this.files[f]);
            })
        },
    },
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/1K7sf12k0k

Comment: I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at FileReader._this.readers.<computed>.onloadend ` but it does like it is working. Why am I getting this error? I get it on this line: `let imgRef = _this.$refs.file[f];`